# How to create and open a Alert Dialog in BackboneJS Application

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, backbone.js, backbone-views

I am developing a Hybrid Mobile Application using jQuery Mobile, BackboneJS and RequireJS.

I want to show an Alert dialog but struggling to get the way to do. jQuery mobile style dialog is not working.

```
<div data-role="popup" id="popupClose" class="ui-content" style="max-width:280px">
    <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-left">Close</a>
    <p>I have a close button at the top left corner with simple HTML markup.</p>
</div>


$("#popupClose").enhanceWithin().popup();
```

Followed few stackoverflow thread but couldn't get it work.

Can anyone help me to show Alert dialog in my Application powered by jQuery Mobile and backbonejS

Comment: Are you using a global selector like `$("#popupClose")` within a view..? Where does this code execute..? Is this html part of a view..? How does the DOM look like..? In short, can you create a [mcve]..?

Answer (score 1):

The popup function just initializes the popup plugin on the element.

If you want to actually open the popup you need to call it with an argument.

```
$("#popupClose").enhanceWithin().popup("open");
```

Ref: https://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.0/docs/pages/popup/

Comment: This line executes. Neither gave error nor works. Is there any Backbone specific dialog available which can be used globally over the Application ?